# Change or rewrite add to cart button functionality "

Tags: function

After clicking add to cart button by a user than i want to show checkout page in a popup instead of redirecting to cart, checkout pages.

My purpose is to show checkout page in a popup after clicking add to cart button

Comment: Could you please provide example code?

Comment: Sorry i have no coding knowledge but there is a plugin "woo checkout popup" works fine but only it's premium version can help me. i want a code or hook to add this php in my child theme free